# GAE Python - GAEUtilities - Cache error

Tags: google-app-engine, cookies

I am running an app on Google App Engine and use GAE Utilities (http://gaeutilities.appspot.com/) to set a cookie that saves a unique ID for the user's visit. Although it seems to work fine when I test it, my GAE Log is overflown with errors for almost every page visit. The error I get is following:

```
2013-04-21 12:00:28.568 /go/social/ag1zfnNwYXJrb21wYXNzch4LEgZDb3Vwb24iEmFmZmlsaW5ldDU3MjkyODgxMAw?src=TWT 200 658ms 1kb Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_6) AppleWebKit/534.24 (KHTML, like Gecko) Contact: feedback@getprismatic.com
184.73.14.223 - - [21/Apr/2013:03:00:28 -0700] "GET /go/social/ag1zfnNwYXJrb21wYXNzch4LEgZDb3Vwb24iEmFmZmlsaW5ldDU3MjkyODgxMAw?src=TWT HTTP/1.1" 200 1573 - "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_6) AppleWebKit/534.24 (KHTML, like Gecko) Contact: feedback@getprismatic.com" "www.gutscheinalm.at" ms=659 cpu_ms=129 cpm_usd=0.000176 app_engine_release=1.7.7 instance=00c61b117c8b8fef32a0647ddfb82622596338
E 2013-04-21 12:00:28.566
Expires: Tue, 03 Jul 2001 06:00:00 GMTLast-Modified: Sun, 21 Apr 13 10:00:27 UTCCache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0Pragma: no-cache
E 2013-04-21 12:00:28.566
Set-Cookie: gaeutilities_session=ag1zfnNwYXJrb21wYXNzciMLEhtfQXBwRW5naW5lVXRpbGl0aWVzX1Nlc3Npb24Yp8kcDA_0b46176b54a9aa056a2af1b140ce9af1; expires=Sun, 21-Apr-2013 12:00:28 GMT; Path=/ 
E 2013-04-21 12:00:28.566
Set-Cookie: gaeutilities_session_data=; expires=Sun, 21-Apr-2013 12:00:28 GMT
E 2013-04-21 12:00:28.566
Expires: Tue, 03 Jul 2001 06:00:00 GMTLast-Modified: Sun, 21 Apr 13 10:00:28 UTCCache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0Pragma: no-cache
```

Can anybody give me some directions on what is causing this error, and potentially how I can fix it? Thanks a lot!

**UPDATE 1**

I identified the code which is calling it, which is in Sessions.py line 523. The aim is to make sure that the page is not cached in the browser. I noticed that another part of code which also uses the 'print' command, also registers the input as an error. Is this normal behavior?

```
def no_cache_headers(self):
    """
    Generates headers to avoid any page caching in the browser.
    Useful for highly dynamic sites.

    Returns a unicode string of headers.
    """
    return u"".join([u"Expires: Tue, 03 Jul 2001 06:00:00 GMT",
        strftime("Last-Modified: %a, %d %b %y %H:%M:%S %Z").decode("utf-8"),
        u"Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0",
        u"Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0",
        u"Pragma: no-cache",
    ])

# make sure the page is not cached in the browser
print self.no_cache_headers()
```

Comment: Is there a stack trace in the log ?
It doesn't look like an error, it loook like someone decided to do some logging with ERROR, rather than INFO for a log level.

Comment: This is the entire log entry. It is registered as an Error in GAE - could it be that is classified wrong?

Comment: Yep, it definately is a possiblity there is no error, but someone is just using the incorrect log level.  In fact you can see the returned status as 200 as well.  So there is no uncaught exception.

Comment: I figured out that it is caused by a simple 'print' command. If I use 'print' in any code, it registers the string afterwards as Error. Not sure if this is normal behavior, and also not sure what to do about it...

Comment: Don't use print.  Use logging. Or if you want to set the headers (and I assume you are using webapp, you should be setting those in the response - https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/responseclass

Comment: THanks a lot Tim. I'm going to give that a try and will add a response once I know the outcome.